# Can the following statement be simplified: ~(P & Q) & ~(R & T)

Tags: logic

[image]

I am a bit rusty on my propositional logic. I'm writting a program and want to see if there is a better way to phrase this. I wanted to 'factor' our the negation, but I think that is illegal.

Comment: Let `W=P&Q` and `Z=R&T`, then you have `~W & ~Z`, and if you want to factor out the negation then `~(W | Z)`. If you don't believe me, do both truth tables and compare.

Comment: I believe you @DanBron, makes perfect sense with a little substitution. Now I am not sure if this actually counts as a simplification however since you substituted

Comment: Undo the substitution. You'll see there's one less operation. Now you only have one `~` instead of two. Simpler indeed!

Comment: Great Scott! Your right

Comment: You still need the extra parens in the "solution" you posted. Otherwise you'll get ambiguities with order of operations. Also, post answers in the answer box, not the question box.

Comment: @DanBron I read somewhere that the disjunction  has lower precedence than the conjuction. However, after a quick search on wikipedia, it appears that there is no standard precendence and can vary from author to author, but in general, dusjunction is lower.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "ambiguities". Good find on De Morgan's law, I never remember the names of the transformations.

Comment: The fewest symbols is not a reasonable notion of simplicity.  There are symbols, particularly parentheses, that are not operations, and would vanish if you represented things in something like Reverse Polish Notation.  In the opposite direction, many people would find the fully distributed negation (four symbols all negated and conjoined) simpler because 'depth' creates complexity for human readers constructions that limit parallelism and force ordering are a form of complexity that demands more 'stack' memory in a reader.  You need a standard of complexity, and an argument for choosing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object: simplify [¬(P ˄ Q) ˄ ¬(R ˄ T)].
(1.) ¬(P ˄ Q) is equivalent to (P → ¬Q).
(2.) ¬(R ˄ T) is equivalent to (R → ¬T).
(3.) final result: (P → ¬Q) ˄ (R → ¬T).
I think this result is simpler for having fewer operations.

Comment: Your final result has 5 operations and 2 sets of parentheses, whereas OP's answer has 4 operations and only one set of parentheses.

Comment: @DanBron Doesn't OP's also have 2 sets of parentheses?

Comment: @Araucaria There's only one pair of parens in his answer, though there's an argument to be made there should be more (as I said in a comment under the question and mobileink said in a comment under his answer). He claims there's support for disjunction having lower precedence than conjunction, and therefore only one set of parens is needed.

Comment: @DanBrown I am not disagreeing with you, but could you list the 4 operations in Matt Mclaughlin's answer and the 5 operations in mine?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Applying DeMorgan's Law we arrive at the following simplification.

With parentheses added: ¬((P ∧ Q) ∨ (R ∧ T))

Comment: i think you need more parens?

Comment: It is a rarely used convention these days, but spacing may be used to indicate association in place of parenthesis.